# hover vs remain

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I used "hover" because, according to the dictionary, it means "**near** a particular level". However, the freelancer I hired to correct my writing changed it to "remain". I think "remain" means "unchanged". "Hover" is more accurate. Which one do you think is more accurate?
Also, does "hover" contradict "fairly stable"?

> Although less fish was consumed than any of the other meats throughout
> the period, its consumption level was **fairly stable**, **hovering
> /remaining** at 50 grams the entire time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few different implications one could derive from it 'hovering', but it is all contextual. Personally, I think it is a pretty good word choice. After all, you've said '***fairly** stable*', which implies some slight fluctuation anyway. 'Hovering' aptly describes it gently moving up or down but around a fixed position. The only thing I would change is to say "*hovering **around** the 50 grams mark*", rather than 'at', which suggests it is a fixed point.

In other contexts, 'hovering' can suggest that something or someone is waiting to make a larger move... like someone raring to go, gently moving in one spot but preparing to move off quickly in a particular direction. It is possible that the word could spark this kind of meaning to some people, but coming right after you speak of stability I think this is unlikely.